# Find value from specific cloumn and merge all of it value's in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I want to find all village code and merge all of it's  value
here is result that I expected

[image: before is my data and after that i want]

Comment: That's a strange way of merging values. You'll have to explain this a bit further. Do all alpha letters go to the left and all numbers to the right?

Comment: i just need merge no matter  the way even if k29k43 that's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With office 365 you could use the following formula in `F3`:

```
=CONCAT(FILTER(B3:B4,A3:A4=E3))
```

Or:

```
=CONCAT(IF(A3:A4=E3,B3:B4,""))
```

The latter would also work with Excel 2019, but you'd need to confirm the formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Edit:

To get the letters to the front you'd need two `CONCATS`, assuming you only got a single letter, something like:

```
=CONCAT(FILTER(LEFT(B3:B4,1);A3:A4=E3),FILTER(MID(B3:B5,2,99),A3:A5=E3))
```

Or:

```
=CONCAT(IF(A3:A5=E3,LEFT(B3:B5,1),""),IF(A3:A5=E3,DEEL(B3:B5,2,99),""))
```

Comment: thank you that's work fine but can how to move all charcter to the begining of cell

Comment: You mentioned it wouldn't matter in your previous comment?

Comment: yeah that's fine completely thank you but i prefrer if you have solution